# Where to put Django OAuth Toolkit middleware in Django 2?

Tags: python, django, oauth, django-oauth

I'm trying to follow a tutorial on the Django OAuth Toolkit: https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/tutorial_03.html. The instructions say to update de `MIDDLEWARE` as follows:

```
MIDDLEWARE = (
    '...',
    # If you use SessionAuthenticationMiddleware, be sure it appears before OAuth2TokenMiddleware.
    # SessionAuthenticationMiddleware is NOT required for using django-oauth-toolkit.
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'oauth2_provider.middleware.OAuth2TokenMiddleware',
    '...',
)
```

In my current project generated using `startproject` in Django 2.0.1, however, I see both `SessionMiddleware` and `AuthenticationMiddleware`, but no `SessionAuthenticationMiddleware`:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    # 'oauth2_provider.middleware.OAuth2TokenMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Where should I put the `OAuth2TokenMiddleware`? After `AuthenticationMiddleware` as in the commented-out line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SessionAuthenticationMiddleware class has been removed - session authentication was unconditionally enabled in 1.10.

(see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#miscellaneous)

i.e. yes, it should come after AuthenticationMiddleware